# Vakhil 14.2.E why $t \mapsto t, \mathcal{O}_X(D) \to \mathcal{O}_X$ is isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I found [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379709/vakil-14-2-e-l-approx-o-xdivs-for-s-a-rational-section) question on MSE. And have misunderstanding. Let $X = \mathbb{P}^1$, $p \in \mathbb{P}^1$ - point, $L=\mathcal{O}_X(p)$.

Then $L_p = \{\frac{p(t)}{t} | p(t) \in k[t] \}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X,p} = \{p(t) | p(t) \in k[t] \}$ where $t$ is local parameter in point $p$. So the formula $f \mapsto f, L_p \to \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is not even define morphism correctly (where we must send $\frac{1}{t}$?). But there is in related SE question:

> Part of the exercise to show that $B = \{open\: U\subset X:\: O(div(s)) \rvert_U \approx O_U \}$ is a base for the Zariski topology on X. On each such set it is easy to see that $O_X(D)(U)\longrightarrow O_X(U)\longrightarrow L(U)$ defined by $t\longmapsto t\longmapsto ts$ is an isomorphism, so in the end we find that $O_X(div (s))\approx L$ .

Hope somebody helps me with my misunderstanding.

Comment: The formula should be $f\mapsto t.f$. As $t$ is a local parameter in $p$, the germs of sections of your bundle at $p$ are exactly your $L_p$. In other words $1/t$ is a $O_{X,p}$ basis of $L_p$.

Comment: @A.Rod But why all such isomorphism in each point of $X$ will gluing into isomorphism between $L$ and $O(D)$ (in terms of related question)?

Comment: Just to be clear, what you want to prove is that if $\text{div}(s)$ is the divisor associated to a rational section of $L$ then $O(\text{div}(s))\simeq L$. You want to prove this in general (say on a normal noetherian scheme) or in your particular case with $\text{div}(t)$?

Comment: I want to prove that in general.

Comment: @A.Rod Can you explain me such thing (don't want to create another question): let $f \in \mathcal{O}(div (s))_{X,p}$ then $sf \in \mathcal{O}_{X,p}?$. Example $X = \mathbb{P}^1$, $s = x_0$, $p = (0,1)$, $f = \frac{1}{x_0}$. So it seems like morphism $t \mapsto ts$ is of type $\mathcal{O}(div(s))_{X,p} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ right?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following you, $s$ is only a section of $L$, so what do you mean by $sf\in O_{X,p}$ it naturally is in $L_p$. The way it goes is the following take $s$ a rational section of $L$, you may chose local trivialisattions of $L$ and $s$ will be carried to an element $f_U$ in $K(O_X(U))$ in each of the trivialisations, and those elements will be related by an element of $O_X(U\cap V)^*$ on the intersection. Then $O_X(div(s))$ is the subsheaf of $K_X$ locally generated by $f_i^{-1}$. Are we on the same page up to this point ?

Comment: Now to prove the general result you can follow the proof in the thread you mention. Or (and this is the way I would do it) prove that you can find a cocycle in $H^1(X,O_X^*)$ that gives both $L$ and $O_X(div(s))$ through the isomorphism $H^1(X, O_X^*)\simeq \text{Pic}(X)$. This should be fairly straightforward.